# Minimize product with known sum and lower bound on each term

Tags: optimization, real-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $0\leq \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$ be a positive real number.

My question is, what is minimum value of $x_1\cdot x_2 \cdots x_n$ over all choices of positive real numbers $x_1,..., x_n\geq \epsilon$ for which $x_1+\dots+x_n=1-\epsilon$?

I expect that the minimum is $\epsilon^{n-1} (1-n\epsilon)$, corresponding to the choice $x_1=\dots=x_{n-1}=\epsilon$ and $x_n=(1-n\epsilon)$, but I cannot prove it.

The condition $\epsilon\leq \frac{1}{n+1}$ guarantees the existence of a solution.

Comment: Did you mean $x_n=1-\epsilon-(n-1)\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @StefanLafon Yes, fixed, thanks